# Astronomy Jokes

Tags: discussion

What are the best astronomy jokes you've ever heard? I'm looking for images; however, you can share whatever you like.

Comment: The IAU. There are more jokes about astronomers than about astronomy.

Comment: https://jcdverha.home.xs4all.nl/scijokes/ is the largest collection I'm aware of. No images though.

Comment: In space, no one can hear you laugh. @barrycarter That list should be sent as a SETI-message to the aliens. If they don't have a sense of humor, then we better ignore them anyway.

Comment: I moved the question to meta because it's definitely off-topic on the regular site, but still interesting enough that it should be appropriate *somewhere*.

Comment: You can always count on [Sidney Harris](http://www.sciencecartoonsplus.com/gallery/astronomy/index.php).

Comment: You can also always count on [Randall Munroe](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/Category:Astronomy).

Comment: Thanks everyone for the links :) Is no earthling interested in posting an answer?

Comment: How many jokes per answer?

Comment: @DanielCann 400,000,000,000 would be a good start.

Comment: @LocalFluff I second that!!

Comment: As long as no one starts with: "are you a string theorist?" "No, I'm a frayed knot".

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[image: The HR diagram of astronomers]

Answer (score 24):

[image]

This annoys so many chemists. :)

Comment: This is by far my favourite!

Answer (score 20):

I like this one.

[image]

Answer (score 19):

[image]

Answer (score 18):

Three astronomers go out for dinner at a conference - an optical astronomer, an X-ray astronomer and a neutrino astrophysicist.

Incredibly, when the soup arrives, they all have a fly swimming about in it.

The optical astronomer uses his spoon to flip the fly out, splashing a lot of soup all over the table in the process.

The X-ray astronomer carefully fishes out the fly with his spoon, picks out the fly and drops the remaining soup from the spoon back into the bowl.

The neutrino astronomer does the same, but taps the fly vigorously, shouting "spit it out, spit out"!

Answer (score 17):

I dare an "answer". [God's finger](http://www.universetoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/carina_hst.jpg) is a natural joke from the heavens. (Don't take it personally, it is meant to all of us)

[image]

Comment: A "positive thinking" interpretation is that it is turned away from us. As in f* all of the universe in that direction. I hope they don't mind, or don't have fingers, rather than having fingers but no minds. Nothing good will come out of this anyway.

Comment: Many with a master and even a PhD in astrophysics get a job in finance instead of in science. Because they know how to count numbers and such, which the economists are clueless about. The accountant sums the numbers a thousand and two trillions to two. Two numbers. Each one put in its own account box in the bank's Excel sheet. But considering the in/deflation and the trillions of dollars of dark deficit and the negative interest rate over spacetime, it seems as if the greedy astro students have made society a disfavour.

Answer (score 12):

What kind of songs do the planets like to sing?
*Nep-tunes*

What does an astronomer blow with gum?
*Hubbles*

A neutrino walks into a bar...and keeps right on going...

Yeah, these were awful but great...

Answer (score 10):

Quantum mechanics = best mechanics
[image]

And this one is on my schools maths classroom

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Poor Disney...

[image]

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Answer (score 7):

A galaxy walks into a tavern. The innkeeper shouts: "Hey you, get out, you're barred!".

Answer (score 7):

How does the man on the moon cut his hair? *Eclipse it.*

Why does a moon rock taste better than an Earth rock?
*It’s a little meteor*

Why didn’t the Dog Star laugh at the joke? *It was too Sirius*

What does a star win in a competition?
*A constellation prize*

What’s the worst thing about throwing a party in space?
*You have to planet*

I'm sorry XD

Answer (score 5):

Two spiral galaxies walk into a bar.

The first one goes up to the bar and asks for two drinks, one for him and one for his friend.

The barman looks suspiciously at the second spiral galaxy and says “I’m sorry but I can’t serve your friend, he’ll have to go.”

The first spiral galaxy complains, “Why can’t you serve him?”

The barman replies, “Because he’s barred.”

Answer (score 3):

I might aswell add a classic joke.

*Did you know entropy used to never be the same?*

Here's another one.

*What did Heisenberg say to Schrodinger when they were restrained from a fight?*

*Let me atom!*

Atom, at him... I'm so good...

Comment: It took me 5 minutes to get the second joke (even though you explained it at the bottom)....LOL :)

Answer (score 2):

Here’s one:

What do you call a peanut in a spacesuit?…  An astronut!

And another!

What is an astronaut’s favorite key on a keyboard?… The space bar.

And one more.. sorry, I love these!:

Why didn’t the sun go to college?… Because it already had a million degrees!

Answer (score 0):

What was the star's least favorite type of music?

*Heavy metal*

*Iron-ic*

A star runs out of hydrogen in its core. When the doctor tells it to start fusing helium, the star says, "I'll *try...I'll-pha get*. Say it fast to understand. The doctor says "Don't forget ca-feed yourself helium!"

I'm Tauri, these jokes suck